# Gparted Shows %100 used disk

Tags: gparted

I have installed clean Ubuntu on my ssd disk and I tried create a partition with gparted but it shows my disk usage %100. Is it bug ?

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of it?

Comment: no i can't i need 15 rep to add image.

Comment: Upload to [Imgur](http://imgur.com/), and add the link.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/5lkt2dr5j/

Comment: From the picture it appears that ubuntu is installed in a Logical Volume Management Physical Volume (LVM2 PV), and not simply in a partition formatted with a file system.  See [Logical Volume Manager (Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) for a description of LVM.  Currently there is no unallocated space within the LVM2 PV and hence the LVM2 PV cannot be shrunk.  You might have unused space within the Logical Volumes within the LVM2 PV.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer:  When you installed Ubuntu, the installation have used the whole drive as 1 LVM partition, and that's why you can't create another partition, since there is no space left.

See if this [helps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124465/how-do-i-shrink-the-root-logical-volume-lv-on-lvm/124480#124480) you shrink the partition.