# GParted showing incorrect used space

Tags: partitioning, gparted

guys,

I've been trying to search a solution for this all over Google, but my effects was of no avail. I wanted to resize my current partition to about 500 GB and create a new partition with all free space remaining. However, for some reason GParted says that I've used all space while the properties clearly states that I've only used 60 GB.

I've also tried using GParted live on USB, but still no luck.

Here's the screenshot: https://gyazo.com/d7cd99f2dfede2bd00ccb674ea89aa15

If you're able to help me with this problem, I'll thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried right clicking the partition and checking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inconsistency is because you're using the Linux [Logical Volume Manager (LVM).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) GParted can't read "inside" an LVM partition, so it's feeding you misleading information. You don't say why you want to resize your storage space, so I can't be sure how you should do the job. There are two broad possibilities:

- **Using the space within Ubuntu** -- If you want to juggle files around for use within Ubuntu (or even another Linux distribution), then you just need to shrink your current logical volume and create a new one, as described in [this question and answers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124465/how-do-i-shrink-the-root-logical-volume-lv-on-lvm)
- **Using the space outside of Ubuntu** -- If you want to clear room for installing another OS or to use the space from another OS that's installed to another disk, then the task is harder, since you must shrink not just the logical volume within the LVM, but also the physical volume (partition) that holds the LVM, as described [in this question and answers.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)

More broadly speaking, you may want to consult [this wiki page on LVM,](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) which presents background information that you may find helpful.